# Google API fetching data error

Tags: php, google-api

When loading the token script :
token.php

```html
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '516195178663-5pgnd88unc38khttmgj67scinlhk7caf.apps.googleusercontent.com'; // Enter your Client ID here
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'QLsIeOBhHLIee4_d-OOqjblK'; // Enter your Client Secret here
$REDIRECT = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$APPNAME = "BrickFame";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
$client->setApplicationName($APPNAME);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    
// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
        die('The session state did not match.');
    }

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    echo "Access Token: " . json_encode($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    try {
        // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
        // currently authenticated user's channel.
        $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array('mine' => 'true'));

        $htmlBody = '';
        foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
            // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
            // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
            // to retrieve that list.
            $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

            $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
                'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
                'maxResults' => 50
            ));

            $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
            foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
                $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
                    $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
            }
            $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
        }
    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = <<<END
<h3>Authorization Required</h3>
<p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorise access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>
 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $htmlBody;?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can fetch my access token and refresh token is shown and i saved it under token.txt

```html
Access Token: {"access_token":"ya29.Ci8tA-3KvN7LE03mLLWsJJOsKHPr3ArvEw9xDaCX8wpFxGM-VpLswYwR1Mnhc7wS1Q","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"1\/BopX8bClCDuDkg0WO9KKyvxKMC-y1GiFhFOO8JQ5HkU","created":1469621552}
```

However when accessing the upload script:
api.php

```html
<?php

$key = file_get_contents('token.txt');

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client_id = '516195178663-5pgnd88unc38khttmgj67scinlhk7caf.apps.googleusercontent.com'; // Enter your Client ID here
$client_secret = 'QLsIeOBhHLIee4_d-OOqjblK'; // Enter your Client Secret here
$videoPath = "videos/example.mkv";
$videoTitle = "Just an Example Title";
$videoDescription = "This is the YouTube video's description";
$videoCategory = "22";
$videoTags = array("first tag","second tag","third tag");

try{
    // Client init
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setAccessToken($key);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        /**
         * Check to see if our access token has expired. If so, get a new one and save it to file for future use.
         */
        if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $newToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
            $client->refreshToken($newToken->refresh_token);
            file_put_contents($key, $client->getAccessToken());
        }
 
        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
 
        // Create a snipet with title, description, tags and category id
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($videoTitle);
        $snippet->setDescription($videoDescription);
        $snippet->setCategoryId($videoCategory);
        $snippet->setTags($videoTags);
        $snippet->setDefaultLanguage("en");
        $snippet->setDefaultAudioLanguage("en");

        $recordingDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails();
        $recordingDetails->setLocationDescription("United States of America");
        $recordingDetails->setRecordingDate("2016-01-20T12:34:00.000Z");
        $locationdetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint();
        $locationdetails->setLatitude("38.8833");
        $locationdetails->setLongitude("77.0167");
        $recordingDetails->setLocation($locationdetails);

        // Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->setPrivacyStatus("public");
        $status->setPublicStatsViewable(false);
        $status->setEmbeddable(false); // Google defect still not editable https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4861
 
        // Create a YouTube video with snippet and status
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setRecordingDetails($recordingDetails);
        $video->setStatus($status);
 
        // Size of each chunk of data in bytes. Setting it higher leads faster upload (less chunks,
        // for reliable connections). Setting it lower leads better recovery (fine-grained chunks)
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet,recordingDetails", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        /**
         * Video has successfully been uploaded, now lets perform some cleanup functions for this video
         */
        if ($status->status['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded') {
            // Actions to perform for a successful upload
        }

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(true);

    } else{
        // @TODO Log error
        echo 'Problems creating the client';
    }

} catch(Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage();
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}

?>
```

It is when i encountered the error : Here is the return value

```html
Caught Google service Exception 0 message is refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessTokenStack trace is #0 /home/vol11_2/freecluster.eu/fceu_18534127/htdocs/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(246): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(NULL) #1 /home/vol11_2/freecluster.eu/fceu_18534127/htdocs/api.php(29): Google_Client->refreshToken(NULL) #2 {main}
```

What might i have missed? Could it be possibly my files error?
I dont understand the line that says : refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessTokenStack trace is #0

Can anyone guide me out? 
Thanks ! :)

Comment: Can anyone helppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp